# Pass two value with two parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax

my current code pass only one parameter value.But I want to pass two values with two parameters.

my current code

```
<script>
function getfilter(str){

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div></script";

    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "Views/mapresult.php?q="+str,
        type: "GET",

        success: function ( responseText ) {

$("#result").empty().append($(responseText)); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

---

```
<li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="'.$cd[$i][0].'" >'.$cd[$i][1].'</li>
```

But i want to pass two parameter

like

```
<li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id1="'.$cd[$i][0].'" id2="'.$cd[$i][0].'" >'.$cd[$i][1].'</li
```

Comment: What a messy script. 1) please format, 2) why mix DOM and jQuery like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $(".android").on("click",function(e) {
    var id1 = $(this).data("id1");
    var id2 = $(this).data("id2");
    if (id1!="") {
      $("#result").html("<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div>");

      $.ajax({
        url: "Views/mapresult.php?q="+id1+id2,
        type: "GET",
    //  data: serializedData,
        success: function ( responseText ) {
          $("#result").empty().append($(responseText)); 
        }
      });
    }
});
</script>



<li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" data-id1="'.$cd[$i][0].'" data-id2="'.$cd[$i][0].'" >'.$cd[$i][1].'</li
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the onclick stuff. You can store the data directly in attributes on your list item.

```
<li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" data-first="Some data" data-second="some other data">Click Me</li>
```

And this javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // listen for clicks on that element
    $('.android').on('click', function(){

        // get the data
        var data1 = $(this).attr('data-first'),
            data2 = $(this).attr('data-second');

        // Send the data to your function. 
        // There are 10 other ways to do this but this'll work.
        getfilter(data1, data2);
    });

});


function getfilter(data1, data2){
    var spinner = "<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div>",
        $result = $('#result');

    // if you're gonna drink the kool-aid, drink it!
    $result.html(spinner);

    // double check however you like.
    if (data1==""){
        $result.html("");
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "Views/mapresult.php?q=",
        type: "GET",
        // Format your data into an object 
        // jQuery will take care of the rest
        data: { 
            "data1" : data1,
            "data2" : data2
        },
        success: function ( responseText ) {
            $("#result").html(responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4kC8b/